# how can i make an IM bot with php without 3rd party?

Tags: php, bots

i've tried playing with imified.com but there are too many issues so i started wondering if i can make one with using core php but couldnt find anything online.
is it possible? and where do i start?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create bot in PHP. Try to use PHP Sockets and run the PHP script from console and attach it to screen or something.

You need to find API documents for the platform you are going to use.  You can find those easily via Google.